# Codeigniter class diagram with some controllers with the same class name

Tags: php, codeigniter, uml, class-diagram

I have a web application build with CodeIgniter framework. I already build my web app, but now I have to make a class diagram for my app.

The problem is, I have 4 controllers with the  same class name.

This directory, for application/controller/ file :

```
 ../application/controller/company/dashboard.php
 ../application/controller/company/jobsheet.php
 ../application/controller/company/joblist.php
 ../application/controller/company/notification.php
 ...etc
```

AND

```
 ../application/controller/student/dashboard.php
 ../application/controller/student/jobsheet.php
 ../application/controller/student/joblist.php
 ../application/controller/student/notification.php
 ...etc
```

Now I have same controller class name with different directory. My solution for now is to name it like this :

```
 company/jobsheet

 student/jobsheet
```

etc.

How to name my class diagram on UML?

Comment: PHP can define namespaces. Namespace gives to class unique name. I would say, you should add namespace to your class definition in php file. See using namespaces in php here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 1):

You can create model in UML very simply. Namespaces are solution .. as Pablo described.
UML defines Package element. Package is namespace. You can define classes in package. Two classes in different namespace can have the same names. Name of element composed of class name and namespaces names is called qualified name. Qualified name precisely identifies class definition. All object oriented environemets support qualified names.

In your example: "application/controller/company/dashboard" is qualified name of dashboard as well. application,controller,company and student are Packages in UML.
UML class diagram of your app can look like following:

[image]

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. am i have to change my code a little bit, using name space?
sory for asking ridiculous question, i never using namespace before.

Comment: PHP can define namespaces. Namespace gives to class unique name. I would say, you should add namespace to your class definition in php file. See using namespaces in php here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: @user3209635 for examples of UML diagram with namespaces ("package") and classes inside see [Spring and Hibernate DAO Classes](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/spring-hibernate-uml-package-diagram-example.html) and other examples at the end of this chapter http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Use namespaces or prefix your classes.

Comment: and, after i give a namespace for every class i had, i named my class on UML class diagram with class namespace?

Comment: Using namesapce is gthe best approach but I don't know if codeigniter support it. I think class prefixes would be better, then you can name your classes in the diagram as usual.

Comment: i already use prefix for my codeigniter framework. the problem is not on the program.. my program is running usual. the problem is when modeling the program. i confused naming my class diagram, because it had same class name..